# Spyder Python IDE - Changing Editor Text Problems

Tags: python, fonts, spyder

I'm new to using Spyder here. How do I get the text editor to show 'Verdana' font? The editor seems to be classified as a 'Plan text font' since it's showing 'Consolas' instead of 'Verdana'.

For reference, the file open is a '.py' file.

I've checked the settings in Preferences -> General -> Appearance

[image: Settings Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You can only choose monospaced fonts for the Editor. If Verdana doesn't fit in that category then you can't choose it, sorry.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Cheers Carlos

Comment: Well, that's the custom with most IDEs and text editors because only monospaced fonts let you get proper indentation of your code.